# Another NoReverseMatch error. Trying to use reverse() in model layer

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls

I tried to find similar topic but any does not help me much.

My error (e.g.):

> Reverse for 'user_activate' with arguments
>   '(u'pU6ARMPCgHeyTAGhBWYwxZqLSUtwqWHqnf9MNEfd',)' and keyword arguments
>   '{}' not found

urls.py:

```
url(r'^user/activate/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$','users.views.activate', name='user-activate'),
```

views.py:

```
def activate(request, key):
    user = User.objects.select_related('profile').get(activation_key=key)
    if user is not None:
       if user.is_active:
           print 'already active'
       else:
          if user.get_profile().check_key_is_valid():
             user.is_active = True
             user.save()
          else:
             user.get_profile().reset_activation_data()
             send_activation_email(user.get_profile().activation_key, user.email)
             print 'key expired'
    else:
        print 'user not found'
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('front'))
```

models.py:

```
def send_activation_email(key, email):
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
    path = reverse('user_activate', args=[key])
    from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
    site = Site.objects.get_current().domain
    url = "http://%s%s" % (site, path)

    from django.core.mail import send_mail
    from my_app import settings
    send_mail('Account activation', url, settings.SITE_EMAIL,
        [email], fail_silently=False)
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have named the url as `name='user-activate'` (with dash), while you are trying to reverse lookup with `'user_activate'` with `'_'`.

Change

```
path = reverse('user_activate', args=[key])
```

to

```
path = reverse('user-activate', args=[key])
```